# How to use MySQL as DB for a django project?

Tags: python, mysql, django, sqlite, ubuntu-16.04

I am trying to learn django. I have gathered basic about this from their official site. I am now trying to read source codes of different projects available on github and trying to understand them.
I am now trying to modify a project on github named ecommerce2, [link](https://github.com/codingforentrepreneurs/ecommerce-2) . I'm trying to use MySQL database instead of SQlite as they did here.
I installed mysql and changed the settings as instructed [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-mysql-or-mariadb-with-your-django-application-on-ubuntu-14-04). But one command here `sudo mysql_install_db` didn't work and said to be deprecated.

Now I'm having following error when I ran `makemigrations` and `migrate` command.

```
ImproperlyConfigured("Error loading MySQLdb module: %s" % e)
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module: No module named MySQLdb
```

I'm on Ubuntu 16.04LTS

Answer (score 1):

You can install mysql db using pip install mysql-python command,if you want specific version of python mysql use pip install mysql-python==1.2.5

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/MySQL-python/1.2.5

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
'NAME': 'django_api_test', # database name
'USER': 'root', # database username
'PASSWORD': 'admin', # database password
}
```

}

Do database setting in setting.py file.
Thanks

Comment: Hi, you got solution or not

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the `PyMySQLdb` module into your Python environment. Do `pip install MySQL-python`, and it should install the MySQL bindings in your Python environment.